# How to route to an outside URL from within MVC controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, url-routing

I'm embarrassed to even ask this question, but not sure of the syntax or way to do this.

I have a controller method where I would like to route to a URL *outside of the MVC application*.  The reason for this is because I am using authentication from another webforms app and would like to clear out any session variables before routing to the other app.

So basically, how can you route to www.microsoft.com from a controller action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Controller.Redirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirect.aspx). Note that this is not technically "routing", it's "redirecting", but should work just fine for you.

Comment: Easy enough, that's perfect.  Thanks Franci.